# Neighbor's furnace exhaust

Tags: furnace

My neighbor's house sits 20ft from mine.  Their furnace exhausts out the side of their house about 3 ft above the ground.  The exhaust is blowing onto the side of my house and into the attic vent.  Their furnace is a newly installed unit.  Is this dangerous or can it damage my house?

Comment: Your attic vent is near this exhaust even though the exhaust is 3ft above ground? Could you post some pictures? I think that would help us visualize what the situation is. Thanks!

Comment: As the exhaust floats up, it is drifting towards the attic vent.  Today is a cold day, so it is very noticeable.

Comment: I have read that this exhaust can be acidic.  Can it damage the house siding?

Comment: Please add new information and questions to the post, not in comments.

Comment: 20 feet away? How do you know it's your neighbors exhaust? 20 feet will dilute any exhaust.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a high efficiency furnace vent etch the brick on my house?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/85152/will-a-high-efficiency-furnace-vent-etch-the-brick-on-my-house)

Answer (score 1):

The water vapor is slightly acidic but not enough to damage plant life in my experience.  At 20’ horizontal and then 7-8’ up the carbon monoxide should be well diluted  but this is probably what you notice, 
almost all of the systems I have installed exhaust to the roof the one that was in a wall was at 9’ , but that may be a requirement for my area as it was specified on the prints.

The one thing I would question is if the moisture stream is actually hitting your house?  if it is ask them to install a 45 or 90 to direct the moisture to the ground as horizontal moisture acidic or not could cause issues.